# Liferay Table Column Description

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to understand the field level description for each table in life ray which are related to user management. I did not understand the purpose of some columns in the following tables.

**USER_:**

```
GRACELOGINCOUNT

FACEBOOKID

PORTRAITID
```

**GROUP_:**

```
PARENTGROUPID

LIVEGROUPID

TREEPATH

TYPE_

TYPESETTINGS

REMOTESTAGINGGROUPCOUNT
```

**ADDRESS:**

```
TYPEID

PRIMARY_
```

**PHONE:**

```
TYPEID

PRIMARY_
```

Can any one please explain the description of the above columns. (Ex: Status column is used to identify whether the user is in active state or not) In the same way I need a brief description of each column which I mentioned above.

Comment: it would help to know the purpose - why do you want to understand them? As this is an implementation detail of the portal that you shouldn't mess around with. Also, how much experience do you have with Liferay? Some of these values should be easy to find on the UI

Comment: I understand "I need to describe..." - *for what purpose?* is what I'd like to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a general description to some of them, but I hope you are not going to meddle with the database directly since that is not recommended (see [Olaf Kock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30208109/468763)) and that could lead to sure problems in the future.

#### USER_

1. `GRACELOGINCOUNT` -
2. `FACEBOOKID` - i am not sure if this is used anymore since now we have the `Contact` table to store id's for `FacebookSn`, `TwitterSn` etc.
3. `PORTRAITID` - This is a foreign key to the `Image` table, which stores information about the User's uploaded portrait.

#### GROUP_

1. `PARENTGROUPID` - Sites can have sub-sites, so the sub-sites would have the groupId of the parent-site.
2. `LIVEGROUPID` - Used for Staging purpose, stores the groupId of the live-site for the Staged Site.
3. `TREEPATH` - Stores the path to the child-site, eases traversing parent-child relationships when they are deep.
4. `TYPE_` - This is used to define different types of Site like public, private, restricted or system. See [`GroupConstants`](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/model/GroupConstants.html) class's properties prefixed with `TYPE_SITE_*`. `0` is for records that are not Sites, see `site` column.
5. `TYPESETTINGS` - Stores some additional configurations for a Site like if you have a [application-adaptor hook](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/customizing-sites-and-site-templates-with-application-adapters) applied for a site or the SEO section etc.
6. `REMOTESTAGINGGROUPCOUNT` -

#### ADDRESS

1. `TYPEID` - This is a foreign key to the `ListType` table, various types of address exists (Billing, Others etc) for `Contact` and `Organization`.
2. `PRIMARY_` - Decides which is the primary address for a user, only one address can be primary.

#### PHONE

1. `TYPEID` - This is a foreign key to the `ListType` table, various types of phone exists (Business, Mobile etc) for `Contact` and `Organization`.
2. `PRIMARY_` - Decides which is the primary phone for a user, only one phone can be primary.

For more understanding it would be good to go through the Liferay API like [`UserService`](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/UserService.html), [`GroupService`](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/GroupService.html), [`OrganizationService`](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/OrganizationService.html) etc and the source-code of the Implementation classes.

Answer (score 3):

So, according to the comments you're integrating external code that accesses this database: Check [this statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30167869/13447) for my opinion on using the database directly, e.g. potentially writing to it.

*You must go through the API* to properly use Liferay's User Management functionality. *Everything* else will lead to *disaster* sooner or later. If you're lucky: Sooner. If not: Later, when you long forgot about this warning.

Check Liferay's API that has specifically been created to allow programmatic access to everything you need. Here's [UserService](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/UserService.html) for example.

Trust me - you'll miss *so* many things in understanding the database that you'll severely upset the API when Liferay finds data (or poisoned caches) later. Been there, done that. It's not pretty.